# Plotting Riemann Prime Counting

Tags: programming, number-theory, prime-numbers

I want to program the formula in [this page](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HowTheZerosOfTheZetaFunctionPredictTheDistributionOfPrimes/). Didn't take me long to get to my code below. But 1) it only plots the prime counting function and 2) evaluation takes incredibly long. How can I fix it?

```
R[x_] := Sum[MoebiusMu[n]/n*LogIntegral[x^(1/n)],{n,100}]
F[x_] := -2*Real[Sum[ExpIntegralEi[ZetaZero[k]*Log[x]],{k,10}]]
M[x_] := Sum[MoebiusMu[n]/n*F[x],{n,100}]
Plot[{PrimePi[t],R[t]-M[t]-1/Log[t]+1/Pi*ArcTan[Pi/Log[x]]},{t,0,10},
PlotRange ->All]
```

EDIT, major problem: If I am changing the amount of zeros, in other words k, the graph stays the same which is not good. It should slowly become a better and better approximation. Please help!!

Comment: Instead of "Real" in the definition of F[x], use "Re", and I think replace Log[x] in the Plot command with Log[t]. The Plot limits should be, say, 2 to 10. The function blows up at 1.

Comment: `RiemannR[]` is now built-in.

Comment: @KennyColnago and please read my edit. The graph won't change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Riemann's solution for the prime counting function is

`Pi[x]=Sum[(MoebiusMu[n]/n) * J[x^(1/n)], {n,1,nmax}]`,

where `J[x]` contains several terms. Define the integral term in `J[x]`.

```
RiemannJint[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1/(u (u^2 - 1) Log[u]), {u, x, Infinity}]
```

Using the first `k` zeta function zeros, the equation becomes

```
Sum[(MoebiusMu[n]/n) * 
    (
     LogIntegral[x^(1/n)]
     - Log[2]
     + RiemannJint[x^(1/n)]
     -2 * Total[Re[ExpIntegralEi[N[ZetaZero[Range[k]]]*Log[x]/n]]]
    ), {n, 1, nmax}]
```

The built-in `RiemannR[x]` covers the contribution of the LogIntegral term.

The (not-so-good) approximation `ArcTan[Pi/Log[x]]/Pi` covers the `Log[2]` and integral (RiemannJint) terms. This approximation is based on `nmax=154`. Thus,

```
approxPi[x_, k_Integer] :=
   RiemannR[x] +
   ArcTan[Pi/Log[x]]/Pi -
   2*Sum[(MoebiusMu[n]/n) *
     (Total[Re[ExpIntegralEi[N[ZetaZero[Range[k]]]*Log[x]/n]]]),
     {n, 1, 154}]
```

For example:

```
ListLinePlot[
   {Table[{x, PrimePi[x]}, {x, 2., 50., 0.5}],
    ParallelTable[{x, approxPi[x, 10]}, {x, 2., 50., 0.5}],
    ParallelTable[{x, approxPi[x, 100]}, {x, 2., 50., 0.5}]},
   ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14},
   PlotRange -> {{2, 50}, {0, 16}},
   PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[{"True \[Pi][x]", "10 Zeros", "100 Zeros"}, {Left, Top}]]
```

[image: poor approximation]

The approximation `ArcTan[Pi/Log[x]]/Pi` has little effect for larger `x`. Removing the approximation improves the fit.

The following code avoids this problematic approximation to `Log[2]` and the integral.

```
RiemannJ[x_, k_Integer] := 0 /; x < 2
RiemannJ[x_, k_Integer] := 
   LogIntegral[x] - Log[2.] + RiemannJint[x] - 
   2*Total[Re[ExpIntegralEi[N[ZetaZero[Range[k]]]*Log[x]]]]
SetAttributes[RiemannJ, Listable]

RiemannPi[x_, k_Integer] := Sum[(MoebiusMu[n]/n) RiemannJ[x^(1/n), k], {n, 1, k}]
```

The corresponding plot compares `Pi[x]` to `RiemannPi[x]`. The plot shows near perfect agreement in the sense that `RiemannPi[x]` converges to `Pi[x]` when `x` is not prime, and converges to `Pi[x]-1/2` when `x` is prime. Using more zeros improves the agreement.

```
ListStepPlot[{
   Table[{x, PrimePi[x]}, {x, 1, 50}],
   ParallelTable[{x, RiemannPi[x, 10]}, {x, 1, 50}],
   ParallelTable[{x, RiemannPi[x, 100]}, {x, 1, 50}]},
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Argument x", "PrimePi[x]   and   RiemanPi[x]"},
   PlotLabel -> "RiemannPi[x]", BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 16}}, ImageSize -> 500, 
   GridLines -> Automatic,
   PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[{"True \[Pi][x]", "RiemannPi with 10 Zeros",
             "RiemannPi with 100 Zeros"}, {Left, Top}]]
```

[image: better approximation]

Answer (score 2):

Using [immediate assignments](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/39-immediate-and-delayed-values.html) and correcting the mistakes pointed out by @KennyColnago, plotting is quick:

```
R[x_] = Sum[MoebiusMu[n]/n*LogIntegral[x^(1/n)], {n, 100}];
F[x_] = -2*Re[Sum[ExpIntegralEi[ZetaZero[k]*Log[x]], {k, 10}]];
M[x_] = Sum[MoebiusMu[n]/n*F[x], {n, 100}];
Plot[{PrimePi[t], R[t] - M[t] - 1/Log[t] + 1/Pi*ArcTan[Pi/Log[t]]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Making the replacement I suggested in the comments: `Plot[{PrimePi[t], RiemannR[t] - M[t] - 1/Log[t] + ArcTan[Pi/Log[t]]/Pi}, {t, 0, 10}]`

Comment: Is it possible to remove the yellow graph in the intervall [0,1.75]? And thank you so much guys! You literally saved my life, I have a presentation tomorrow, phew...

Comment: @vitamin, use `CondtionalExpression[(* stuff *), ! (0 < x < 7/4)]` for that.

Comment: @J.M. okay thanks. Did you read my other comment above? If you don't want to answer it, no problem. Can ask a new question.

Comment: @vitamin, that should definitely be a new question (but you can link to this one for context).