# How to use the nontrivial zeros to fit the PrimePi?

Tags: plotting, education

As [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/239531/21532), I make a gif in follow:

```
RiemannJint[x_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[1/(u (u^2 - 1) Log[u]), {u, x, Infinity}]
RiemannJ[x_, k_Integer] := 0 /; x < 2
RiemannJ[x_, k_Integer] := 
 LogIntegral[x] - Log[2.] + RiemannJint[x] - 
  2*Total[Re[ExpIntegralEi[N[ZetaZero[Range[k]]]*Log[x]]]]
SetAttributes[RiemannJ, Listable]

RiemannPi[x_, k_Integer] := 
 Sum[(MoebiusMu[n]/n) RiemannJ[x^(1/n), k], {n, 1, k}]

LaunchKernels[];
imgs = Table[
   ListLinePlot[{Table[{x, PrimePi[x]}, {x, 2., 50., 0.5}], 
     ParallelTable[{x, RiemannPi[x, i]}, {x, 2., 50., 0.5}]}, 
    ImageSize -> 350, PlotRange -> {{2, 50}, {0, 16}}, 
    PlotLabel -> (ToString[i] <> " zeros are used")], {i, 5, 500, 5}];

ListAnimate[imgs]
```

[image]

But it's obviously different from the animation provided by wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#/media/File:Riemann_Explicit_Formula.gif), which uses 200 nontrivial zeros, which perfectly matches the `PrimePi` function:
[image]

I know the formula is $f(x)=\operatorname{li}(x)-\sum_\rho\operatorname{li}(x^\rho)-\ln 2+\int_x^\infty \frac{\mathrm dt}{t(t^2-1)\ln t}$, but I don't know how to deal with that $\sum_\rho\operatorname{li}(x^\rho)$ with *MMA*. This is my current try as [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/226601/21532):

```
countPrime[x_, k_] := 
 LogIntegral[x] - N[Re[Total[ExpIntegralEi[ZetaZero[Range[k]]*Log[x]] + 
      ExpIntegralEi[(1 - ZetaZero[Range[k]])*Log[x]]]]] - Log[2] + 
  NIntegrate[1/(t (t^2 - 1)), {t, x, Infinity}]
```

But it looks a lot different than built-in `PrimePi`. Can anyone plot the wiki animation using *MMA*?

Comment: Your sampling interval `0.5` is quite big - so it is not a surprise it does not look nice - especially the slopes at each step are not perpendicular because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `si` is sampling interval then it is also a good choice to shift sampling by `si/2` in case of function with discontinuities so that the samples fall evenly spaced before and after discontinuity.

So use the following in your code (for even more precise plot use smaller `si` than `0.5`):

```
si=0.5;
ListLinePlot[{Table[{x, PrimePi[x]}, {x, 2.0 - si/2, 50., si}], 
  ParallelTable[{x, RiemannPi[x, i]}, {x, 2.0 - si/2, 50., si}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 350, PlotRange -> {{2, 50}, {0, 16}}, 
 PlotLabel -> (ToString[i] <> " zeros are used")]
```

Comment: Shift sampling doesn't seem to fit the logic of the formula used

Comment: Do not understand what you mean. It is not shifting of a function. It is shifting of the choice of samples - it does not affect the function itself - it only affects it appearance of the plot a for big `si` - for small or negligible `si` it has no effect at all.